# Css - How to override css for a table cell

Tags: css

css newbie question -
we have a generalized css defined for Table along with its Table Cells as:

```
.table {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 1em 0 1em 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #A3C0E8;
    border-left: 1px solid #A3C0E8;    
}

.table td, .table th {
    padding: .6em;
    border-right: 1px solid #A3C0E8;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #A3C0E8;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background:#D7E8FF;
    color:#333;
}
```

In one scenerio, I want to override td style so that I can show an icon image in front of Table Cell text.
so, if Table Cell is defined as - `<td> Vehicle Name & Details </td>`

I want to apply style for this Table Cell so that it also show icon image in front of text - 'Vehicle Name & Details'.

I added this style in css file -

```
.vehicle { background:url(mainFolder/img/icons/vehicle.png) no-repeat left center; }
```

and added to td as `<td class="vehicle"> Vehicle Name & Details </td>` 
but no icon is being shown. Parent table of this td is `<table class="table">`

Am I missing something?

Thank you!

Comment: This could be a browser issue. What browser are you developing on, testing on and targeting?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`.vehicle` (one class selector) is *less* [specific](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity) than `.table td` (one class selector + one type selector).

You need either:

- a *more* [specific](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity) selector (e.g. `.table td.vehicle`)
- an *equally* [specific](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity) selector (e.g. `td.vehicle`) in a rule-set that appears later in the stylesheet

Comment: Thanks for your reply...nice explanation. One furher query - how can I make the icon to appear before text, right now it's being overlapped with text.

Comment: you have to add some padding to the `.vehicle` class, or add the icon as an `img` and float it left to the text.

Answer (score 1):

Change your selector to `td.vehicle` also make sure it appears after `.table td` selector in your css file.

You can also make the special td's style inline:

```
<td style="background:url(mainFolder/img/icons/vehicle.png) no-repeat left center;">...</td>
```

Answer (score -1):

Double check to make sure your URL location is correct. I would first put in an absolute path (http://site.com/mainFolder...) first, then change it to a relative path.

Answer (score -1):

try replacing the background position to

```
      background:url(mainFolder/img/icons/vehicle.png) no-repeat left top;
```

You can also change the no-repeat to repeat for debuging purposes to see if the image loads.

Also i advice u install firebug (if you are using firefox) so you can manipulate html and css on the fly.

Answer (score -1):

It should work, make sure that the route to the image is correct. And also note that is a background image you are setting, so if you don't want the image to be behind the text you have to use padding --> [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasalguero/aWAaD/)

Comment: Could I know why after providing a working answer with a working example I got a down vote?

Comment: The example only works because the HTML was modified so the original styles don't match. i.e. not because you made the URL to the image correct (which it already was), but because you stopped the original background being set in the first place.

Comment: Ah, that was my fault then, although downvoting without commenting doesn't help to understand things like this. In this case an alternative answer to Quentin would be to use the !important attribute in the css style http://jsfiddle.net/jasalguero/aWAaD/2/ although his is better

Comment: `!important` is an ugly, one-shot hammer that just causes maintenance problems down the road.

Comment: I agree, that's I said your answer was better :D