# Best way to forcefully override the CSS for a TD Cell

Tags: css, html-table

I want to override the style of a TD with a background colour.

My problem is that I have (mechanically) generated table which puts a CLASS on all TR for Zebra Stripes.

So I have

```
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr class="myTROdd">...
  <tr class="myTREven">...
   <td class="myBackRed">Highlight this cell</td>
```

My CSS knowledge is weak, but as I understand it

```
.myBackRed {background-color: #FF0000;}
```

is less specific, so does not work.

```
.myTREven TD.myBackRed {background-color: #FF0000;}
```

is specific and does work, but I want something more generic, for example I tried this (which doesn't work)

```
.TABLE TD.myBackRed {background-color: #FF0000;}
```

The problem I have with

```
.myTREven TD.myBackRed {background-color: #FF0000;}
```

is that the actual CMS Template is

```
  <tr class="my{TAG}TROdd">...
```

where {TAG} is substituted with any one of a large number of optional "Adjustment" values, and I am trying to avoid having to code every possible combination in style sheet for my cell-override style

Example of the Fiddle, below with TD override style for rows 3-4, no explicit override CSS for rows 5-6

[image: Example with CSS for rows 3-4, no CSS for rows 5-6]

https://jsfiddle.net/dB93J/1240/

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956048/css-how-to-override-css-for-a-table-cell) comes close, but doesn't solve my problem.

**EDIT:** As per @Roberrrt comment I've changed

```
.TABLE TD.myBackRed {background-color: #FF0000;}
```

to

```
TABLE TD.myBackRed {background-color: #FF0000;}
```

and that does indeed seem to override the cell regardless of the variation to the TR class.  See new fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dB93J/1247/

Comment: Small side note, your example `.table` doesn't exist. Did you mean `table` an sich?

Comment: Ah, good point, thanks. I'll try that.  I've just tried `!important` which seems to solve the problem, but I'm uncomfortable with what the pecking-order is when I use that (due to my lack of CSS knowledge)

Comment: Crated a new fiddle with TABLE instead of .TABLE and looks like that's fixed it.  Still uncomfortable with my lack of knowledge in case there is a "better way". New fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/z3m91cqt/

Comment: I'm a bit busy, so I couldn't read your question thoroughly, but this is an excellent resource on CSS specifity: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

As at all, I still make simple class/element mistakes like above as well, and that usually takes up half an hour a day.

Comment: The last fiddle you have shared changing the color of 5 and 6th row TD. That is what you want right?

Comment: It might be worth introducing something like `Less` into this as it should make the process easier.

Comment: @ Suresh Ponnukalai Thanks, yet. I want a generic way that `myBackRed` override the style and colours the cell

Answer (score 0):

If the understanding about your issue is correct. This is the possible answer for your problem. At first I select the class name of this TR tag with a class="myBackYellowTREeven" and TD tag with a class="myBackYellowTROdd". Below, is my solution...

```css
.zui-table {
    border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    font: normal 13px Arial, sans-serif;
}
.zui-table thead th {
    background-color: #DDEFEF;
    border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
    color: #336B6B;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}
.zui-table tbody td {
    border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
    color: #333;
    padding: 10px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}

/* NOTE myTROdd is not defined */

.myTREven,.myTREven TD
{
    background-color:#f1f1f1
}
.myBackYellowTROdd
,.myBackYellowTROdd TD
{
    background-color: #fffccc;
}
.myBackYellowTREven
,.myBackYellowTREven TD
{
    background-color: #fff799;
}
/* .myBackRed */ /* This is what I would like to define! ... */
/* , .myBackRed TD */ /* ... or this even ... */
/* , .TABLE TD.myBackRed */ /* ... or EVEN THIS */
 .myTREven TD.myBackRed
, .myTROdd TD.myBackRed /* In case myTROdd defined in future */
/* , .myBackYellowTROdd TD.myBackRed */ /* Do I really need this for EVER possible TR style? */
/* , .myBackYellowTREven TD.myBackRed */ /* DITTO */
{
    background-color: #FF0000
}

/* MY SOLUTION */
tr.myBackYellowTREven td.myBackRed,
tr.myBackYellowTROdd td.myBackRed {
background-color: #FF0000}
```

```html
<table class="zui-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Height</th>
            <th>Born</th>
            <th>Comment</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="myTROdd">
            <td>Jason Thompson</td>
            <td>PF</td>
            <td>6'11"</td>
            <td>06-21-1986</td>
            <td>Normal ODD Row</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="myTREven">
            <td>Fred Bloggs</td>
            <td>PF</td>
            <td>5'7"</td>
            <td>01-08-1988</td>
            <td>Normal EVEN Row</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="myTROdd">
            <td>DeMarcus Cousins</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td class="myBackRed">6'11"</td>
            <td>08-13-1990</td>
            <td>ODD Row with Red cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="myTREven">
            <td>Isaiah Thomas</td>
            <td>PG</td>
            <td class="myBackRed">5'9"</td>
            <td>02-07-1989</td>
            <td>EVEN Row with Red cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="myBackYellowTROdd">
            <td>Ben McLemore</td>
            <td>SG</td>
            <td class="myBackRed">6'5"</td>
            <td>02-11-1993</td>
            <td>Yellow ODD Row
                - Red cell missing</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="myBackYellowTREven">
            <td>Marcus Thornton</td>
            <td>SG</td>
            <td class="myBackRed">6'4"</td>
            <td>05-05-1987</td>
            <td>Yellow EVEN Row
                - Red cell missing</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: But wouldn't I have to make a style for every combination of {TAG} substitution in `<tr class="my{TAG}TROdd">` which would require a new `tr.my{TAG}TREven td.myBackRed,` for every possible {TAG}? That's what I'm trying to avoid (which I think the generic-solution in the EDIT to O/P solves)

Comment: Pardon me, I did not able to read the CMS part. I though at first you only need to access this specific part.

Comment: Try to add this following code in your css.

table.zui-table tbody tr td.myBackRed {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}